# Extra slash in redis output

Tags: redis

In the following example, why do I get an extra slash \ at the end of the string.

```
[root@server src]# echo 'testme one more word new line' | ./redis-cli -x set mytest
OK

[root@server src]# ./redis-cli 
redis> get mytest
"testme one more word new line\"
```

In the above example, I do not want the \ in "line\". It is not there in the original echo statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I'm getting is not a backslash, but a break line (backslash+n).
That is added by the "echo" command. You can use `echo -n` to avoid that extra break line:

```
$ echo -n 'testme one more word new line' | ./src/redis-cli -x set mytest
OK
$ ./src/redis-cli get mytest
"testme one more word new line"
```